# Interpreting the correlation between random variables using the double angle formula.

Tags: probability, statistics

I currently have that

$$
\rho_{12} \geq \frac{(\rho_{13}+\rho_{23})^2}{2} - 1
$$

where $\rho_{ij}$ is the correlation between random variables $X_1, X_2, X_3$ where $X_1, X_2, X_3$ all have mean 0 and variance 1. There was a claim in my book that this can be interpreted geometrically by the double angle formula. However, I am failing to see this, does anyone have any hints? Thanks!

Comment: No double angle here. $\rho_{13}=\cos(\phi_1)$, $\rho_{23}=\cos(\phi_2)$, $\rho_{12}=\cos(\phi_1+\phi_2)$. Substitute and simplify. Correlation coefficient can be though of as cosine of an angle between RVs similar to regular dot product.

Comment: How were you able to have $\phi_1+\phi_2$ for $\rho_{12}$? Are you assuming that $\phi_{12} > \phi_1+\phi_2$? Or do we have to assume this in order to prove the inequality above? that the inequality above shows a special case of where $\phi_{12} > \phi_1+\phi_2$? Thanks!

Comment: Angle between $X_2$ and $X_3$ plus angel between $X_3$ and $X_1$ is equal to angle between $X_2$ and $X_1$ by geometric interpretation. No assumptions other than $\phi_3=\phi_1+\phi_2$ up to a sign (but cosine is even, so it doesn't matter) as in interpretation above.

Comment: Hi, I got a relation of: $cos(\phi_1)^2 + cos(\phi_2)^2 + 2sin(\phi_1)sin(\phi_2) \leq 2$, but dont know how to simplify any further because it seems whatever bounds I give it, it yields a higher number and hence has a tight bound. do you have any hints? Thanks!

Comment: Your cross term is wrong. Get it right, convert everything into sines and factor. If you need help with factoring, think about values of angles when the bound is tight - factors must be zero at those values.

Comment: I just changed it, is this form correct or were you talking about the one with the cosine in the cross term? Thanks

Comment: ok, think I got it, I used the $1-sin(\phi_1)^2 = cos(\phi_1)^2$ and then got the bound of $-(sin(\phi_1)-sin(\phi_2))^2+2 \leq 2$. Thanks so much for your help!!!